# jQuery .append not appending

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, append

I'm trying to add posts as the user reaches the #marker-end in an HTML page using jQuery/LazyLoadXT:

This is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#marker-end')
        .on('lazyshow', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/get_content_item/',
                dataType: "html"
            })
            .success(function (responseText) { **note that I tried .done also**
                // add new elements
                $('#infinite').append(
                    $('<div>')
                        .append($.parseHTML(responseText))
                        .find('#infinite')
                        .children()
                );
                // process added elements
                $(window).lazyLoadXT();
                $('#marker-end').lazyLoadXT({visibleOnly: false, checkDuplicates: false});
                });
        })
        .lazyLoadXT({visibleOnly: false});
});
```

and there's this in my HTML page:

```
<div id="infinite"></div>
<div id="marker-end"></div>
```

The ajax call is working, and in Chrome developer tools I see a response from the server, so I know the problem is somewhere with the appended data not showing up with jQuery. The code is similar to the [LazyLoadXT page](http://ressio.github.io/lazy-load-xt/demo/index.htm), however I can't get it working.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: If you think the append isn't working, break it down into smaller parts. Start with `console.log(responseText)`

Comment: Additionally, you should never use `.success`, it's deprecated and removed in future versions. Replace it with `.done` (though, as you have noted, this might not fix your existing problem)

Comment: @kevinb Thanks for the heads up. I added the log, and it's showing the expected server response.

Comment: Next step is to inspect the results of `$('<div>').append($.parseHTML(responseText)).find('#infinite').children()` If it doesn't contain the element you want, break it down further to figure out why.